# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.getInfoFromToken')

Tags: react-native

I write two functions inside the class component  here it is

```
facebooklogin = () => {
    console.log('fblogin');
    LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']).then(
      function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log('Login cancelled');
        } else {
          console.log(
            'Login success with permissions: ' +
            result.grantedPermissions.toString(),
          );
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
            // console.log(data);
            // console.log(data.accessToken.toString());
            const accessToken = data.accessToken.toString();
            this.getInfoFromToken(accessToken);
          });
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error);
      },
    );
  };
getInfoFromToken = token => {
console.log(token);
},
```

when I call facebooklogin() it shows this error
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 4):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.getInfoFromToken')

Comment: what if you move the getInfoFromToken logic inside the getCurrentAccessToken callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `this.getInfoFromToken(accessToken);` you're trying to access `this` from a `function`, which in strict mode equals `undefined`.

You can try making it an arrow function instead, which will make inner `this` references apply to the contextual `this`, which seems to be the purpose in the code above.

You'd only need to change line 4:

```js
      function (result) {
```

For an arrow function declaration:

```js
      (result) => {
```

Does it do the trick?

Also, you may want to add a `.catch()` callback to the `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` promise chain (if it returns a promise-like object, as it seems).